# Некоректная работа OC Archlinux. Черный экран с бесконечно мигающим белым нижним подчеркиванием

Tags: linux, archlinux

При запуске системы выбивает черный экран с бесконечно мигающим белым нижним подчеркиванием находящийся слева сверху, при перезагрузке система может нормально запуститься но запускается нормально через раз, что это может быть и как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: все что угодно. Например, видеокарта неплотно прилегает или мышка. И они раз оно проскакивает, второй - нет. Или кто то греется и в нагретом состоянии (или наоборот - в холодном) не работает. Надо смотреть логи (тот же dmesg)

Comment: непонятно у вас сама система зависает или может графический сервер неподымается, пробовали переходить в другую tty консоль ? Ctrl+Alt+FN где N = 1, 2, 3...

Comment: ставлю на блок питания

Comment: @Zt. При загрузке ядра останавливается после успешно запущенных но не всех мудулей ядра и выбивает нижнее подчеркивание

Comment: @KoVadim зависает после разных загрузок модулей, бывает после "Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status" или бывает после "Started Accounts Service"  или какого то другого модуля...

Comment: @Zt. Никако-го результата...

Answer (score 0):

При запуске нажми `incert`, или `del`.  Должно вывести лог загрузки. Оттуда должно быть понятно в чем дело

Comment: Ничего не происходит после нажатия